# Is there a simple way to use 'find -ls' without showing username/group?

Tags: linux, find

I'm writing an audit trail on a release note.

Currently I'm finding to-be-released items before the deploy and screenshot them.

I use command below:

`find -ls | grep item001.class;find -ls | grep item002.class;find -ls | grep item003.class;` ... etc

The thing is that I don't want unnecessary username and group shown, so I tried this:

`find -ls | grep item001.class | awk '{$5=$6=""; print $0}';find -ls | grep item002.class | awk '{$5=$6=""; print $0}';`

It does the job, but it removes the highlights of the filenames and the command line becomes too messy for other people.

Question :
Is there a better way to replicate `ls -gG` results with `find` command?

Comment: Why use `find | grep` instead of `find -name`? Are you looking for `find -name item001.class -exec ls -gG {} +`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-printf FORMAT` to print using any kind of format you like. See `man find` for details. Specifically:

```
$ ls -ldgG /
drwxr-xr-x 18 4096 Jan 20 13:44 /
$ find / -maxdepth 0 -printf '%M %n %s %Tb %p\n'
drwxr-xr-x 18 4096 Wed Jan 20 13:44:54.5514843650 2021 /
```

Not precisely the same since the `ls` datetime output can't really be replicated in `find` in any case.